# Winless sucessfully compiles .less file however no .css file is created

Tags: css, less

I am using [WinLess](http://winless.org/) to compile a `*.less` file into a `*.css` file.

The file is reported as compiling successfully, however no `*.css` file is being created.

Other `*.less` files appear to compile and create the `*.css` files normally, so I do not think this is an installation issue.

Any ideas on why a particular `*.less` file will not compile while others will?

---

**Edit**: The contents of the problem file are included in the main .less file through an `@import` statement. If I comment out the `@import` statement and paste the original contents of the imported `*.less` file into the main file then everything compiles correctly. Other files `@import` correctly -- just this one has an issues being *@imported*.

Very odd.

Comment: hmm, is it possible you are looking for it in the wrong directory?

Comment: Why don't you try removing 99% of it and see if it compiles? If it does, then keep adding in sections to perform a binary search to find the issue.

Comment: Good idea Hayk -- going through doing that now...

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I've run into the same issue.

Comment: No -- the problem still exists. I ended up copying the contents of the one .less file I was having a problem with -- which was being @import in the main .less file. Once I placed the contents in the main file the CSS was created correctly. For some reason the import was failing.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem with both winless and simpless (mac). Usually this is caused by a line of code that for some reason is stopping the compilation but not giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried double-checking your LESS syntax? Sometimes I paste code into my LESS file, and it breaks the compilation process, for example

```
#sample-class { ... }
```

the ellipsis is not legal LESS code, and WinLess stops compiling CSS until it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. Re installed it and it started working fine.